# Will web master tool crawler SQL (database)

Tags: php, mysql, google-search-console, bing-webmaster-tools

Am saving all page data in SQL and retrieve it using PHP.

Will web master tools like GOOGLE WEB MASTER, BING WEB MASTER,etc will crawler all data in database

so that it display result on search engine

Because web master tools will find title and text in HTML or PHP page, but in my case I save all title and data in SQL.

If I save data in SQL database web master will crawl it or not?

Comment: How do you think other websites store their data?

Comment: No, web crawlers have no direct access to your database, they don't even know you have a database, they only know what they can see on the page

Comment: I think the question is clear not sure why on hold

Comment: @Yann: it's rather vague what the OP is actually trying to do. If the question is just "can a crawler get direct access to my database" then the answer is "no" (thankfully).

Comment: Yes, the person is clearly a begginner I understand, but what he's asking is very clear in my opinion. He was affraid that Google wouldn't be able to crawl his title because he uses PHP and MySQL to generate it. I believe he don't even realize it would be a security problem if crawler could acces his database eheh

Comment: @YannChabot security problem..? by crawler how can crawler create security problem if it access database

Comment: Because this would mean that any "bot" (or crawler) can come into your database and sneak every data. There is some information that you don't want crawler to know (User personnal informations and such for example). This is why you always keep your database connection password as safe as possible so nobody can know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in your database will not be crawled. Crawler will, however, crawl every data you input in your page. Crawler are like user, they load every page of your website they can find an read the HTML that is outputted. But nobody can access your database unless you give them the code for it. Just make sure that you output the right thing in your html pages.

Your title will be read by crawler because the data are sent by PHP from your database, and the server then send a HTML output result. They won't read your database but they will read what you see on your website (your title and etc) becasue you ask PHP to output them.

Comment: because there is only one php file like page output that will display page content loaded from sql

Comment: Exactly, when you load a webpage, what happen is that the server check out your PHP, you output data in the HTML page and then the server send to the browser an HTML page, without any trace of PHP in it. So the user (or the crawler) will see only plain HTML (with your css, javascript and etc) but they will not be able to see what's in your database and what's generated via PHP and/or your database.

Comment: in my page i have list of title each title contains link to database (content of page  Eg:- PHP is my title, and content will be all about PHP ) its same as stackoverflow here we have various question and answer to question i would like to store all data to database instead of creating page , can web master crawle

Comment: Yes, it will be crawled. But they won't crawl your "database" directly. They will crawl the same thing that the user can see.